# ajax trouble not parsing the json data php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

facing a problem while parsing see below code

```
$('#topselector').change(function(){
                var url = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/ajax/get-all";
                //var selecter_id = $(this).val();
                //alert(selecter_id);

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("success");
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        console.log(obj);
                        if(obj.meta.code === '200')
                        {
                            alert("ok");
                            $.each(obj.data, function(i,v){
                                //alert(v.builder_name);
                                $("#browsers").append("<option value="+v.builder_project_id+">"+v.builder_name+"</option>");
                            });

                        }
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                           alert("Error"); 
                    }
                });
            });
```

getting the output till success after that alerting i.e ok.

my json response is like

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "s_no": 1,
            "builder_project_id": "389",
            "builder_name": "1 389 Sath Build Home",
    },
    {
            "s_no": 348,
            "builder_project_id": "4",
            "builder_name": "348 4 NA",
    }
    ]
}
```

I cant understand where i am doing mistake pls suggest in console getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: add your php code also.

Comment: already added in url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON output is invalid.

It is putting unnecessary commas at the last element of the array.

Observe, the removed comma after `builder_name`'s values.

Corrected JSON:

```
$json = '{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "s_no": 1,
            "builder_d": "389",
            "builder_name": "1 389 Sath Build Home"
    },
    {
            "s_no": 348,
            "builder_project_id": "4",
            "builder_name": "348 4 NA"
    }
    ]
}';
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/462178)

Comment: i dont think json is wrong as i tested it in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ it showing fine

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with type check with `===`:

```
if(obj.meta.code === 200) // <------change to number here
{
    alert("ok");
    $.each(obj.data, function(i,v){
        //alert(v.builder_name);
        $("#browsers").append("<option value="+v.builder_project_id+">"+v.builder_name+"</option>");
    });

}
```

another thing i want you to suggest is that you should add:

```
dataType:"json",
```

in your ajax which automatically parses the json string. So you need not to use `$.parseJSON()` explicitly.

Comment: _not working_ is not helpful. can you elaborate more about it.